# grep for special characters in R

Tags: r, regex

I am searching for "1." in a matrix in R using grep function. grep("1\.",VADeaths,value=TRUE). However, it is not showing me 41.0 in the result. Why is it so? 41.0 is one of the values in one of the columns.

Comment: This won't work.  The number `41.0` is stored internally as `41`, and when you cast to character, there won't be a decimal component.  Maybe update your question and tell us how you ended here.

Comment: You could convert to character using `sprintf`, for example `sprintf("%.1f", 41)`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped.

Answer (score 0):

If we convert in to `character`, this will become more apparent

```
as.character(VADeaths)
#[1] "11.7" "18.1" "26.9" "41"   "66"   "8.7"  "11.7" "20.3" "30.9" "54.3" 
#[11] "15.4" "24.3" "37"   "54.6" "71.1" "8.4"  "13.6" "19.3" "35.1" "50"
```

For `41`, it is just round and there is no `.` there

If we need to get those elements as well

```
grep("1\\.|^[^.]*1$", VADeaths, value = TRUE)
#[1] "11.7" "41"   "11.7" "71.1"
```